# Proof Math induction Proof $\{ a\} = \mathop \cap \limits_{n = 1}^\infty (a - \frac{1}{n},a + \frac{1}{n})$

Tags: real-analysis

Proof    $\{ a\}  = \mathop  \cap \limits_{n = 1}^\infty  (a - \frac{1}{n},a + \frac{1}{n})$

I  want to show
 if  $x \in \mathop  \cap \limits_{n = 1}^\infty  (a - \frac{1}{n},a + \frac{1}{n})$ then $x = a$ 
By Mathematical Induction

Let $P(k):x \in \mathop  \cap \limits_{m = 1}^k (a - \frac{1}{m},a + \frac{1}{m})$

(1) If k=1
$x \in \mathop  \cap \limits_{m = 1}^1 (a - \frac{1}{1},a + \frac{1}{1})$
$x \in (a - \frac{1}{1},a + \frac{1}{1})$
$x \in (a - 1,a + 1)$

P(1) is TRUE

(2) Let P(k) is TURE 
$x \in \mathop  \cap \limits_{m = 1}^k (a - \frac{1}{m},a + \frac{1}{m}) \cap x \in (a - \frac{1}{{k + 1}},a + \frac{1}{{k + 1}}) = x \in \mathop  \cap \limits_{m = 1}^{k + 1} (a - \frac{1}{m},a + \frac{1}{m})$
       But if $x \in \mathop  \cap \limits_{m = 1}^k (a - \frac{1}{m},a + \frac{1}{m})$ then $x = a$  SO
        If $x \in \mathop  \cap \limits_{m = 1}^{k + 1} (a - \frac{1}{m},a + \frac{1}{m})$ then $x = a$

Such that
        P(k+1) is TRUE

From (1) and (2) and Mathematical Induction then
        if  $x \in \mathop  \cap \limits_{n = 1}^\infty  (a - \frac{1}{n},a + \frac{1}{n})$ then $x = a$

i not sure it true or false ,Thank

Comment: $P(1)$ is not true as $x\in (a-1,a+1)$ doesn't imply $x=a$. In fact, i think using induction is not such a good idea to prove this.

Comment: I didn't get what you want to prove. If you want to prove $RHS=a$, you have to prove no other element but $a$ belongs to the set.

Comment: I don't think induction is the best way to do this problem.

Answer (score 7):

This is not something that you can prove by induction. Simple induction is used when you have a statement $P(n)$ about integers $n$, and you want to prove that $P(n)$ is true for all $n$ greater than or equal to some $n_0$; the present theorem is not of this type at all. To prove that

$$\bigcap_{n\ge 1}\left(a-\frac1n,a+\frac1n\right)=\{a\}\;,$$

you must show two things:

1. $a\in\bigcap_{n\ge 1}\left(a-\frac1n,a+\frac1n\right)$, and
2. if $x\in\Bbb R\setminus\{a\}$, then $x\notin\bigcap_{n\ge 1}\left(a-\frac1n,a+\frac1n\right)$.

To prove (1), you must show that for each $n\ge 1$, $a\in\left(a-\frac1n,a+\frac1n\right)$; this is trivial. To prove (2), you must show that if $x\in\Bbb R$, and $x\ne a$, then there is some $n\ge 1$ such that $x\notin\left(a-\frac1n,a+\frac1n\right)$; for this you need the fact that if $\epsilon>0$, then there is a positive integer $n$ such that $\frac1n<\epsilon$.